# visual studio 2015 remote debugger save permissions between sessions

Tags: visual-studio-2015, remote-debugging

I am using the VS2015 update 3 remote debugger with VS2015 Professional update 3. 
I can debug just fine, but each time I start the remote debugger I have to set up the permissions (add users, set rights, etc).

I am using windows 10 and the debug target is running windows 7.

Is there any way to trick the remote debugger into remembering the permission settings between debugging sessions?